# Azure Cosmos SQL queries very slow, possible to optimize performance?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Querying a collection that holds about 250k items and I need to pull back most of it. These items are partitioned by weeknumber. I've tried slicing the query up into many smaller queries but it seems the fastest I can have it return data is ~500 items/sec. I only want items that have a date within the past 3 months. The querying is done from my Vue web app client side. Any links or suggestions are welcome.

```
SELECT
                    c.weeknumber,
                    c.item_txt,
                    c.item,
                    c.trandate,
                    c.trandate_unix,
                    c.trandate_iso,
                    StringToNumber(c.TOTAL_QTY) AS total_qty,
                    StringToNumber(c.MA_TOTAL_QTY) AS ma_total_qty,
                    StringToNumber(c.IN_TOTAL_QTY) AS in_total_qty,
                    StringToNumber(c.CA_TOTAL_QTY) AS ca_total_qty
                FROM c
                WHERE c.trandate_unix >= ${threeMoAgo_start / 1000} AND c.trandate_unix <= ${threeMoAgo_end / 1000}
```

Comment: A good first place to start is with the Data Explorer in the portal. After running your query, what are the provided query stats?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's a bit unclear what your specific issue is. Perhaps you could clarify how you indexed your collection, what your RU cost is, etc? Also: moving 250,000 documents around might take a while. Curious: is your Cosmos DB instance in the same region as your main application? Please be sure to edit your question with as many details as possible so that others can help you.